# Prove lim $a_n^{{1}/{t}} = a^{{1}/{t}}$ if $ a_n \geq 0$ for all n.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Suppose $a_n \rightarrow a$ as n$\rightarrow \infty$, and $t,n$ are natural numbers. Prove lim $a_n^{\frac{1}{t}} = a^{\frac{1}{t}}$ if $ a_n \geq 0$ for all n.

I want to prove the previous statement using the following identity $x^k - y^k = (x-k)(x^{k-1} + x^{k-2}y + .....+y^{k-1})$

which yielded $(a_n^{\frac{1}{t}})^k - (a^{\frac{1}{t}})^k =   (a_n^{\frac{1}{t}} - a^\frac{1}{t})(a_n^\frac{k-1}{t} + a_n^\frac{k-2}{t}a^\frac{1}{t} + . . . . +a^\frac{k-1}{k} )$.

Not sure how to go on with it. I know that if k=t, then the LHS becomes $a_n - a$ which could be related somehow to the definition of the limit. Also, I suspect that convergence $\Rightarrow$ boundedness could be used. Any ideas.

Comment: Have you looked at the proof that the square root function is continuous? I imagine it would be similar.

Comment: What do you mean by $(\lim a)^\frac{1}{t}$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant $(lim(a_n))^{1/t}$. I fixed that.

Comment: @TrevorGunn I would like to stay away from the definition of continuity for the moment!

Comment: By continuity I just mean that $\lim \sqrt{a_n} = \sqrt{a}$ if $a_n \to a$. I imagine this proof is similar for $t$-th roots.

Answer (score 1):

$1.$ For $a=0$ it is easy enough.

$2.$ Let $a>0$. Then $\exists N \in \Bbb{N}$ and $c>0$ such that $a_n \geq c, \forall n \geq N$

> We use the identity $b-a=(b^{\frac{1}{t}}-a^{\frac{1}{t}}){\sum_{j=1}^tb^{\frac{t-j}{t}}a^{\frac{j-1}{t}}}$

Now $\forall n \geq N$ since $a_n \geq c$ then ${\sum_{j=1}^ta_n^{\frac{t-j}{t}}a^{\frac{j-1}{t}}}\geq {\sum_{j=1}^tc^{\frac{t-j}{t}}a^{\frac{j-1}{t}}}$
$$|a_n^{\frac{1}{t}}-a^{\frac{1}{t}}| \leq |a_n-a|\frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^ta_n^{\frac{t-j}{t}}a^{\frac{j-1}{t}}}\leq |a_n-a|\frac{1}{\sum_{j=1}^tc^{\frac{t-j}{t}}a^{\frac{j-1}{t}}}$$
You can continue from here.

Comment: Thank you. But I really did not understand what that means. I guess I'm too dumb:(

Comment: @Morcus edited my answer..hope this helps

Comment: I see now. So if you want to choose a specific N, will $\epsilon$/ summation terms work?

Comment: I did not understa the last part of your question